# Servlet - isUserInRole()

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

**Spec:**

Servlet: 3.0
Java: 7
Tomcat: 7.0.54

**Intro:**

It is possible to check programatically if user has a specific role using method *HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()*

For example:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException{

    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    //get username and password manually from Authorization header
    //...
    request.login(username, password);

    if (request.isUserInRole("boss")) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }

    request.logout();

}
```

This works fine, but this solution requires to manually retrieve username and password from Authorization header and then login using these credentials.

**Questions:**

Is it possible to just do something like that? With no retrieving data from header and manually login()?

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException{

    if (request.isUserInRole("boss")) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }

}
```

**Trying to answer myself:**

From my understanding this code requires proper configuration in web.xml. This example works with this configuration in web.xml file, for example:

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>boss</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>DefaultRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

But this means that programatically checking roles is not required since configuration in web.xml it is all we need to restrict access.

**Summary:**

- is it possible to programatically checking roles without specifing restrictions (auth-constraint) in web.xml?
- if not, does this mean, that using *isCallerInRole()* performing only checking for additional roles, becouse main required role is specified in web.xml?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
Since the first answer suggest adding *login-config* element to my web.xml, I must say I already have it. I added this to code snippet, as I didn't include it when posting question. And example works with this configuration. But when I remove *auth-constraint* or the whole *security-constraint*, presence of *login-config* is not enought.
I added info about container: Tomcat 7.0.54.

Answer (score 3):

**Question1:**

Is it possible to programatically checking roles without specifing restrictions (auth-constraint) in web.xml?

*Answer:*

Yes, it is possible. There is no need to specify restrictions in web.xml. There is no need to put *scurity-contraint* in web.xml.

In addition there is no need to manually retrieve credentials from header *Authorization* and then manually *login()*.

**Solution:**

Here is a working example:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException{

    request.authenticate(response);              //solution

    if (request.isUserInRole("boss")) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>DefaultRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

And that works.

As you see method *HttpServletRequest.authenticate()* is used nad does the trick. 
Documentation says:

> Triggers the same authentication process as would be triggered if the request is for a resource that is protected by a security constraint.

That is all we need.
I hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your issue, if you are using Basic authentication, add this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ourRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: @win_wave, I already have it, and I added in in my code snippet (see edit1).

Comment: then, probably better to go with Shiro

Answer (score 0):

The basic authorization mechanism provided by servlets in web.xml is basic and mostly 'hard-coded'

If you want to implement a more elaborate way of checking user roles/authorizations, you need to secure your servlets then you have a few possibilities:

- properly implement JAAS. There quite few tutorials around; here is one for [Tomcat](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-authentication-in-tomcat-example)
- a probably more powerful alternative is to use [Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/)